# Bootstrap Fixed Navbar Behavior

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can somebody explain what is going on here?

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7.

Why are `.container` elements invisible?

```
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Big Brother</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" href="/message">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>something</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Invisible</h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<h2>` is not invisible, it's hiding behind your navbar.

You're using a navbar that uses fixed positioning. This takes it out of the normal document flow where it doesn't take up space so the elements after it begin to flow as if it wasn't there.

If you add `padding-top: 50px;` to `<body>` you will see your `<h2>`.

If you read through the [Bootstrap Navbar Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) you'll notice a callout that says **Body padding required**.

Comment: So, I should always pad my body by the size of nav bar? If it is fixed-top

Comment: At the minimum, yes. Bootstrap's navbar starts at a height of 50px. It's up to you if you'd like a little extra padding or not.